# Should tags have "resources" which can be attached to it and which will be shown?

Tags: feature-request, tags

> ***Spawned from here:*** [Community split between SO and project mailinglist/IRC channel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118652/community-split-between-so-and-project-mailinglist-irc-channel)

The basic idea is to be able to attach "resources" or links to a tag which will then be shown in the moment the user chooses that tag. Here, let me draw you some ugly mock-ups:

[image: Absolutely ugly mockup.]

The benefit of this is that users can be more efficiently be guided to Bug-Trackers, official documentation and other stuff.

Upsides:

- Project maintainers can more efficiently channel their SE audience.
- Some Off-Topic and Not-So-Fitting questions (Bug reports f.e.) are taken away from SE.
- The possibility that we teach people something (because they'll visit those links) rises.

Downsides:

- Those need to be displayed somewhere/somehow. My mockup might not be the best idea.
- Those need to be maintained, but I think this will work like the tag wikis do.

Another idea might be to make the tag-wikis more visible and easier to find...but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: isn't this what the tag wiki is for..?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Basically, yes. But the tag wikis are not really easy to find, in my opinion and are not *that* easily visible.